# What is the difference in using an apostrophe between UK and US?

Tags: apostrophe, transatlantic-differences

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dollhouse): UK doll's house
[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doll-s-house): US dollhouse

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/year-s-end): UK year end
[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/year-end): US year's end

In the first example, an apostrophe is typical for UK and not typical for US.
In the second example, it's exactly the opposite: an apostrophe is typical for US and not typical for UK.

Why are these collocations different in terms of using an apostrophe?

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=year+end&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) seems to indicate that _year end_ is quite widely used in the US. The 'dollhouse' thing is just a case of the terms evolving differently.

Comment: This has little to do with an apostrophe (which is a device by which, for some weird reason, written English attempts to make more distinctions than the real, spoken, language does). The point is that the dialects differ in whether this is a possessive structure or a compound.

Answer (score 1):

No particular rule, just different collocations in different dialects.

This is not particularly something to worry about.  I'd have no trouble understanding "I was playing with the dollhouse" and "The year's end results were published."  Indeed, I'm not particularly aware of those being Americanisms.

In the case of "Dollhouse", the compound word is actually slightly earlier (1764) than the form "doll's house" (1783)  Though both could have existed in (childish) speech earlier. (Use of "doll" to mean a child's toy dates only to about 1700).  An advert in the Argos (British) shows "Doll house" and "Dollhouse" and "Dolls house" all in use in Britain.

I think Cambridge is rather splitting hairs with the year('s) end example.  I'm pretty sure you'll see both forms in both countries.